# On the fundamental theorem of field extensions

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I'm re-reading the fundamental theorem of field extensions. (K is normal $\iff$ K is a factorization field.)

Assume $K=F(\alpha_1, \dots , \alpha_n)$, is the factorization field of $f\in F[x]$, over the field $F$. Then for each $\alpha\in K, \alpha = g(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$, for some $g\in F[x_1\dots,x_n]$. Finally define $h\in K[x]$ by $$h=\prod_{\sigma\in S_n}(x-g(\alpha_{\sigma(1)},\dots,\alpha_{\sigma(n)}))$$
Here $S_n$ is the symmetric group of order $n!$ .

It was particularly hard for me to reason through proving that the coefficients of $h$ are polynomials (with coefficients in $F$) of the elementary symmetric polynomials of $\alpha_1, \dots , \alpha_n$. Furthermore by applying Vietas formulas for $f$ we find that its coefficients are symmetric polynomials (with integer coefficients) of its roots: $\alpha_1, \dots , \alpha_n$. My book hereby concludes that $h\in F[x]$.

I may be just tired by now but I feel like there is a step or two missing in the above conclusion. Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: What you call "factorization field" seems to be what is more generally known in english as "splitting field".

Comment: I get it now. The conclusion trivially follows from the premises. The simplest of things are sometimes the hardest to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the Vieta formula for each coefficients is unchanged when we permute the $\alpha_i$ by any element of the symmetric group. This means that each coefficient is a symmetric polynomial.

But all symmetric polynomials of the roots of a polynomial $f$ have their values in the base field. This is essentially the converse of Vieta's formulas.

Comment: Yes, and therefore, by the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials the coefficients of $h$ are polynomials (with coefficients in F) of the elementary symmetric polynomials of $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$.

Comment: With all due respect, sir, what you said is not what I'm asking about.